# Firebase addSnapshotListener not getting documents but getDocuments() is

Tags: swift, firebase

I am trying to attach a snapshot listener to a database reference that I know has documents in it. For some reason, the addSnapshotListener does not return any documents, but using getDocuments() on the same reference yields the expected results. Any reason why this would be?

```
let userRef = db.collection("users")
friendsListener = userRef.addSnapshotListener({ (snapshot, error) in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }

        for document in snapshot.documents {
            print(document.data())
        }
    })
userRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }
        for document in snapshot.documents {
            print(document.data())
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just your "()"

I have removed some here, see if that will do the job:

```
        friendsListener = userRef.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }

        for document in snapshot.documents {
            print(document.data())
        }
    }
```